# no sections in FetchedResultController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I insert and save managed objects:

```
  MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

  MyCity* city = (MyCity*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"City" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  city.cityId = dict[@"id"];
  city.cityName = dict[@"name"];

  NSError *error;
  if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
```

I perform FRC request:

```
  _fetchedResultsController = nil;
  if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
```

This is my FRC:

```
  if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
  }

  MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"City"
                                          inManagedObjectContext: context];
  NSSortDescriptor *sd1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cityName" ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd1, nil];

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
  [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

  NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
  [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                      sectionNameKeyPath: @"cityName"
                                               cacheName: @"cache"];
  [self setFetchedResultsController: theFetchedResultsController];
  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

  return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

After `performFetch` I see:

```
_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects //array of MyCity objects
_fetchedResultsController.sections //empty array
```

why _fetchedResultsController.sections is empty?

when i don't use `[context save:&error]` , i can see array of objects in _fetchedResultsController.sections.

is there issue with saving context in my code? How should I save nsmanagedobject and nsmanagedcontext ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `dict` is empty, so `cityName` is empty and there are no section headers.

Also, you should be holding a reference to your managed object context rather than repeatedly going to your app delegate to get it.

I would also recommend to test your code without `fetchBatchSize` and with `cache:nil` and optimize later.

Also note that the usual pattern is to do a fetch when you lazily create the FRC before returning it. You can then either `nil` it out to generate the fetch, or call `performFetch` on the existing instance.